# Не работает цикл while

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Последовательность состоит из натуральных чисел и завершается числом `0`, не входящим в последовательность. Найти сумму квадратов всех чисел последовательности.

Мой неправильный код:

```
z=int(input())
q=0
while(z!=0):
    q+=z**2
print(q)
```

```
Sample Input:

1              
2
9
7
5
0
Sample Output:

160
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вводите не последовательность, а единственное целое число и сохраняете его в переменную `z`. Если пользователь введет число отличное от `0`  - цикл будет вечным, т.к. условие `z!=0` - будет всегда истинным.

Если не хотите использовать список или кортеж для хранения элементов последовательности - можно сделать так:

```
q=0
while True:
    z = int(input())
    if z == 0:
        break
    q += z**2
print(q)
```

---

```
1
2
9
7
5
0
```

---

```
160
```

Comment: Я кажется понял, спасибо!)

Comment: https://stepik.org/lesson/213098/step/8?auth=registration&unit=186305

Comment: Код понятный, но на сайте не робит

Comment: @SyntaxError, уберите все символы `...:` - это особенности интерактивной среды `iPython`

Answer (score 1):

```py
result = 0
while True:
    x = int(input())
    result += pow(x, 2)
    if x == 0:
        break
print(result)
```

Comment: Элегантное решение, но, к сожалению, не будет работать из-за особенностей ввода чисел. Кстати, я бы сделал так `print(sum(int(x)**2 for x in input().split()))` ;)

Comment: и вправду, упустил что ввод построчно